# Two Spring WebApplicationInitializers detected on classpath

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot

After I converted my maven spring-boot project into a multi module project I started getting error at tomcat server start up at server;

```
2 Spring WebApplicationInitializers detected on classpath
```

Though it works fine if I run it locally via IntelliJ.

Any Idea? Maybe Spring-boot starter dependencies should be in the child module that packages as war, and not in the parent module?

Note: the other question about this here at SO didnt help

Comment: It isn't an error it is an informational message.

Comment: @M. Deinum oh ok but application wont start without any other messages.

Comment: Add more information to your question (projects structure poms etc. ).

Comment: @ M. Deinum Since you said that i checked other log files too. I see "IllegalArgumentException: LoggerFactory LoggerFactory is not a Logback LoggerContext but Logback is on the classpath."

Comment: I have same situation with my spring boot in tomcat, it causes the application to behave like multiple instances and the camel starts processing multiple times. Any fix done for this situation , please share

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and after doing a new basic spring boot with the bare minimum I still had this problem. The last thing left was to check the innocent application.properties and found with trial and error that there was an invalid property. Once this line was removed, everything worked.

This was the property:

```
logging.level.org.apache.catalina=DEBUG
```